# Haskell implemented without a stack?

Tags: haskell, stack, continuations, stackless, graph-reduction

from [How does a stackless language work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016218/how-does-a-stackless-language-work/1016234#1016234)

```
Haskell (as commonly implemented) does not have a call stack; 
evaluation is based on graph reduction.
```

Really? That's interesting, because while I've never experienced it myself, I've read that if you don't use the strict versions of the fold functions and then force the evaluation of an infinite fold you get a stack overflow. Surely that indicates the presence of a stack. Can anyone clarify?

Comment: Let me apologize; I wrote that answer, and sometimes I make up good-sounding crap :)  I've since learned that Spineless Tagless G-machine does not imply Stackless.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not by any means an expert on this, but I think the answer you quoted is not entirely accurate. Haskell doesn't have the straightforward kind of stack most imperative languages have, where you can trace a path of calls through a program. Because of its laziness, evaluation is based on graph reduction, which you can read about [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Graph_reduction), but calls are still eventually placed in a stack. According to [this](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html#tracing) page, "The “stack“ in GHC's execution engine bears little resemblance to the lexical call stack." So yes, there's a stack, but it's very different from one you would find in an imperative language, and it's created using graph reduction.

Comment: `Because of its laziness, evaluation is based on graph reduction` - really? Is graph reduction necessary for laziness? Or is this just a design decision in *some* implementations of Haskell runtimes?

Comment: There's a lot about this in [the haskell wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Graph_reduction). I don't think it's necessary, but it seems like it's the best way to do it.

Comment: Would a stackless haskell mean that there wouldn't be instances of stack overflow problems?

Answer (score 1):

Haskell is not "stackless" or anything like it. Code generated from Haskell source still has some kind of symbols and execution shows some stack traces but they're very loosely related to source code. Here's some information about attempts of simplifying debugging/tracing/profiling:

http://www.haskell.org/wikiupload/9/9f/HIW2011-Talk-Marlow.pdf