# What happens if you directly use LL grammar for an LR parser, after making basic syntactical changes?

Tags: parsing, grammar, ll-grammar, lr-grammar

sorry for the amateurish question. I have a grammar that's LL and I want to write an LR grammar. Can I use the LL grammar, make minimal syntactical changes for it to fit with an LR parser and use it? Is that a bad idea? Are there structural differences between them that don't translate?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760423/why-right-recursive-grammar-is-not-appropriate-for-bottom-up-lrk-parsing ,

Answer (score 2):

All LL(1) grammars are LR(1), so if you had an LR(1) parser generator, you could definitely use your LL(1) grammar, assuming the BNF syntax is that used by the parser generator.

But you probably don't have an LR(1) parser generator, but rather a parser generator which can only handle the LALR(1) subset of LR(1) grammars. All the same, you're probably fine. "Most" LL(1) grammars are in LALR(1), and it's pretty rare to find a useful LL(1) which is not. ([This pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6492798/1566221) is unlikely to arise in a practical grammar, for example.)

So it's probably possible. But it might not be a good idea.

Top-down parsers can't handle left-recursion, and without left-recursion you can't write a grammar which represents left-associative operators, which is to say most arithmetic operators. This problem is usually solved in practice by using a right-associative grammar along with an idiosyncratic evaluation function which corrects the associativity. That's less than ideal. Also, LL grammars created by mechanically removing left-recursion tend to be very hard to read.

So you are probably best off using a grammar designed for LR parsing. But you probably don't have to.